# How to save URL entered in textfield in jsp page, to send it to controller

Tags: ajax, jsp, url, urlencode

I have a jsp page which has form(customerDetailForm) containing textfield to store URL, which through ajax call is going to controller and then to DB.
When I save some URL,I am getting javascript error "400 bad request" .
I read somewhere I need to encode url before sending it as url in parameter.
I have 2 question
1. how to encode URL
2. how and where to save encoded url in customerDetailForm

Since finally I am calling "customerDetailForm.serialize()" before sending to controller

In below code "fbUrl" is a URL with many special character.
CustomerDetailForm is having 2 fields, both are required to be send, "fbUrl" and "userName".

### Code snippet

$.fn.editFbUrl = function (IdentificationNo, customerDetailForm, fbUrl) {

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/useradmin/customers/edit/fbUrl/"+ IdentificationNo,
    data: customerDetailForm.serialize(),
    type: “POST”,
      dataType: "json",
    error: function() {
    },
    complete: function(data) {
        handleAjaxResponse(data);
    }
});
return false;
```

};

Comment: Can you provide us with what you have tried?

Comment: I have updated. Any help really appreciated. In some special Url its breaking . And some are transferred without breaking. How to ensure all URL are transferred safely

Comment: Are you using any security framework?

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURIComponent() function to encode the URL string.

This function encodes the following special characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

```
var encUrl = encodeURIComponent(fbUrl);
url: "/useradmin/customers/edit/"+encUrl+"/" IdentificationNo,
```

Comment: i want to send formdetail which is having all detail,